# Import Data from ODBC to SQL Server and make it live

Tags: sql-server-2016

Is there a way to import data from an ODBC connection AND make it live data?  Meaning a constant flow.  I know of the Import wizard but wasn't sure if that was a one time deal or not.

Comment: Use a linked server? What does "constant flow" mean? Do you need to be able to reference in queries, or do you need some kind of automatic ping back whenever rows are changed in the remote server

Comment: Yes I basically need to replicate everything over to the sql server in near real time.

Comment: You need to [edit] this question to explain what **other** server or data provider you have, ideally you want a trigger on that to push changes over.

Comment: I did, in the title it says it’s coming from an ODBC connection.  I am asking in general.  Odbc to sql....can it be done?

Comment: ODBC is not a database, it's a connection mechanism. What DBMS is the other provider?

Comment: Progress database.

Comment: Progress 11.7.3

Comment: No idea anything about it. But  best to [edit] and explain that, and tag the question with it, so that others can pick up on it. You are probably looking at creating triggers at source to send data to SQL Server. The other option would be to create "linked servers" in SQL Server so that you can refer to the Progress DB directly in a query